# Modeling a schedule

Tags: anylogic

I am simulating the process of an emergency room. I have a problem with patient arrivals.
I have the total number of annual patients, and the probability of distribution of arrivals over the different months and days of the week. For example: total number of arrivals 120000, which divided by the 52 weeks that make up a year is about 2308 per week and therefore 329 per day. However, if we are in May, I know that there are a few more arrivals, so I have to multiply the weekly arrivals by 1.05 and therefore 2423 per month.
Can I set up this reasoning through schedules?

Answer (score 0):

The **Source** object has an option to create agents based on a database datable. Furthermore, it doesn't have to be a record per arrival but several arrivals at the same time. See [here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/connectivity/source-db.html) for more details.

Comment: However, in this way I have to put a specific number of arrivals per day? If I wanted to simulate the activity of an entire year it would be impossible! Isn't there a way to dynamically change the schedules parameters?

Comment: Yes, if **Source** is set to be using `Arrivals defined by: Rate schedule` option then there is an additional `Modify Rate` expression that enables changing `baseRate` number to some other number. This is where a multiplier can be applied.

Comment: Thank you Artem! I'll try this method